# If a paper cites a work and its translation, is it counted as two citations for calculating h-index?

Tags: citations, bibliometrics, translations

If a bibliography mentions a work two times, once in its original and once in its translation, how does this count in the author's H-index?

E.G.:

1. Everyman, J. (2000), A work on citations, Cambridge.
2. Everyman, J. (2001), Un lavoro sulle citazioni, Roma.

The (2) is the italian translation of the (1). 
This means that the author gets 2 citations, but they actually refer to only 1 work. How does this affect citation count and metrics?

Answer (score 2):

The h-index, as usually employed, does not take translations into account. The case you cite would be effectively the same as citing two genuinely different publications by the same author. Under certain circumstances, this might increase you h-index by 1. I leave it to you to decide whether this is fair or not.

Comment: Any source for this answer? Do you know how, say, Google Scholar handles this? Is a work and its translation collapsed into the "All N Versions" link in GS, and if one paper cites multiple "versions" that GS has collapsed into one publication, how is the citation count reported in GS?

Comment: Thank you Koldito. If I understood you correctly, you're saying that citing both versions in the bibliography would be a non-correct practice?

Comment: It guess that it doesn't really matter how google scholar counts it, as citations in ArXiV papers,  tech reports or just "pdfs on academic web pages" also count towards the h-index. Only citations in peer-reviewed publications should normally count for the h-index. So google is off from the usual way of counting anyway.

Comment: @DCTLib There is some difficulty in defining "peer-reviewed publication."  Is it only journals in ISI Web of Science?  What about crappy but non-predatory journals? What about conferences?  What about reports? Where do you draw the line?  My point is, Google is making one of several reasonable choices in this computation.

Comment: @jakebeal - True. It's just not the choice that you would use for computing your h-index when you want to list it in a job or grant application --- whichever you end up using. If you have to later justify your h-index value and exercise sheet pdfs show up in the list of citations, then this doesn't look good...

Comment: @FraEnrico: I only told you how the h-index works. Whether citing both versions is a correct practice is a totally different issue. Personally, unless each version contains material that the other doesn't, I'd only cite one of them (preferably, the English language one, which is presumably accessible to a wider readership).